# Safe way to localize bash scripts?

Tags: bash, localization

In the [BashFAQ of Gregs's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/09), the following is written:

> Don't mark strings that contain variables or other substitutions.

and

> Bash (at least up through 4.0) performs locale expansion before other substitutions. Thus, in a case like this:

```
echo "The answer is $answer"
```

> The literal string $answer will become part of the marked string.

Now I can understand that using variables in strings marked as translatable is security-wise dangerous as described in http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/bash.html.
However, neither removing the variables nor splitting the strings is viable, as this makes the translation difficult/impossible (because of the different sentence structure in e.g. Russian, French, German and English).

So my question is: Does any sane and safe way of bash localization exists, or does one use a more expressive programming language (like Python, Ruby or Perl) when it comes to localization?

Comment: Not sure enough to post an answer, but http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/localization.html might help

Comment: @David Souther Thank you for your comment, which was indeed helpful. If the information is up to date, it is exactly what I was looking for. For the future reader, here is another link about bash localization I've stumbled across: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/internationalizing-those-bash-scripts. Unfortunately, they have neither written about security nor about the quite useful gettext.sh script.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/localization.html looks like a good tutorial for Bash localization using gettext, but I have not used it.